# How can I define the activation function as a hyperparameter in PyTorch through RAY.Tune?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, hyperparameters, ray

This is the link to the main page of the topic I want.

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/examples/tune-pytorch-cifar.html#tune-pytorch-cifar-ref

But unfortunately, there is no good documentation to answer all the questions.
Also, if you know how I can define nested cross validation in this environment, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows.

```
n_samples,n_features=X_train.shape
class NeuralNetwork (nn.Module):
def __init__(self,n_input_features,l1, l2,l3,config):
    super (NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.config = config
    self.linear1=nn.Linear(n_input_features,4*math.floor(n_input_features/2)+l1)
    self.linear2=nn.Linear(l1+4*math.floor(n_input_features/2),math.floor(n_input_features/2)+l2)
    self.linear3=nn.Linear(math.floor(n_input_features/2)+l2,math.floor(n_input_features/3)+l3)
    self.linear4=nn.Linear(math.floor(n_input_features/3)+l3,math.floor(n_input_features/6))
    self.linear5=nn.Linear(math.floor(n_input_features/6),1)

    self.a1 = self.config.get("a1")
    self.a2 = self.config.get("a2")
    self.a3 = self.config.get("a3")
    self.a4 = self.config.get("a4") 
@staticmethod
def activation_func(act_str):
    if act_str=="tanh" or act_str=="sigmoid":
        return eval("torch."+act_str)
    elif act_str=="silu" or act_str=="relu" or act_str=="leaky_relu" or act_str=="gelu":   
        return eval("torch.nn.functional."+act_str)
def forward(self,x):
    out=self.linear1(x)
    out=self.activation_func(self.a1)(out.float())
    out=self.linear2(out)
    out=self.activation_func(self.a2)(out.float())
    out=self.linear3(out)
    out=self.activation_func(self.a3)(out.float())
    out=self.linear4(out)
    out=self.activation_func(self.a3)(out.float())
    out=torch.sigmoid(self.linear5(out))
    y_predicted=out
    return y_predicted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, l1=120, l2=84):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, l1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(l1, l2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(l2, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

and

```
config = {
    "l1": tune.sample_from(lambda _: 2**np.random.randint(2, 9)),
    "l2": tune.sample_from(lambda _: 2**np.random.randint(2, 9)),
    "lr": tune.loguniform(1e-4, 1e-1),
    "batch_size": tune.choice([2, 4, 8, 16]),
}
```

then you can see that l1 and l2 in the init function are config parameters to be tuned for the Net architecyure. You can do the same for your use and add an arbitrary activation function as a parameter in the **init** of the Net class and add use a tune.choice for different activation in the config dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wrote my answer below this question, I would be happy to know your opinion.